# why is background image shifting on page change?

Tags: css

on this website:
http://www.erikbijma.nl/

when I go from this page
http://www.erikbijma.nl/clients/

to the home page, the header logo image shifts to the left then back in place.
How can I fix this?

thanks

Comment: What browser are you seeing this issue? Just tested it on Firefox and looks good.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the scrollbar. To counter this, make the page shorter. I could be wrong.

Comment: in chrome there seems to be no issue too. guess Kyle is right

Answer (score 0):

It's the scrollbar. While its loading, the content is shorter than the window - so it doesn't show scrollbar. But when it loads entirely, it becomes longer than the window - and it shows the scrollbar.

The solution is to always show the scrollbar - when the content is shorter it will show, but it will be disabled.
That is how Facebook did it.

Just add  `overflow:scroll;`  to your `body` tag.